# Does off-topic votes get any more attention?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, off-topic

Sometimes when I browse older questions I find questions that are clearly off topic for StackOverflow and should be migrated.

So I vote **close - off-topic** on the question. But the problem is the question was asked one year ago has totally 100 views. This means that the question will not get 5 close votes for ages.

Do the question I voted "off-topic" get more attention by e.g. moderators or 10k users, so it makes sense for me to vote "off-topic"? or should I flag the question for moderator attention instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have tools where we can see recent off-topic (and other close) flags, so yes; it is useful to do that. There will be lots of different cases of old questions/answers that will eventually be moderated in some way due to refining of the focus of the sites over time.